# Efficient way to compute 3D indexes from 1D array representation

Tags: c++, math, cuda

I have a 3D data, that are stored in 1D array. I compute the 1D indexes like this:

```
index = i + j * WIDTH + k * WIDTH * HEIGHT
```

Than I need to get original `i,j,k` indexes back from `index`. The obvious way to do this is something like this:

```
k = index / (WIDTH * HEIGHT) 
j = (index % (WIDTH * HEIGHT)) / WIDTH
i = index - j * WIDTH - k * WIDTH * HEIGHT
```

But I wonder, is there some more efficient way to do this? At least without the modulo...

Context of this question - I have a kernel in CUDA where I access the data and compute `i, j, k` indexes (the `index` corresponds to unique thread ID). So maybe there is some CUDA-specific way to do this? I guess this is quite common problem, but I couldn't find a better way to do this...

Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: I don't think there is any way to get those values back, what you suggested yourself is definitely wrong. For instance: i=2 j=3 k=4 WIDTH=100 HEIGHT=100. This would make index = 2 + 300 + 40000 = 40302. You say k = index/(WIDTH*HIEGHT) = 40302/10000 = 4,0302. As you can see that is not the same as the original k.

Comment: It will always work if you expect `i, j, k` to be an integer.

Comment: What you've got is fine; if you want to avoid the modulo (since that's very expensive on gpus) you can just do with `j` what you've done with `i`: `j = (index - (k*WIDTH*HEIGHT))/WIDTH`.   If you want it to look a little clearer, and don't need the original index, you can do `k = index/(WIDTH*HEIGHT); index -= k*WIDTH*HEIGHT; j = index/WIDTH; index -= j*WIDTH; i = index`.

Comment: I would also ignore the suggestions about rounding up to a power of 2; in this (not too bad) case it would increase memory requirements of your 3d array by 60% and memory on GPU is generally already tight; and making your arrays powers-of-two size might cause problems with bank conflicts, depending on your access patterns.

Comment: @JonathanDursi: That's a great reply. I think you should add it as an answer. This situation comes up often on GPUs since the 3 dimensions that are supported directly by the hardware often is not enough, causing more dimensions to have to be packed into the existing ones. I've been cringing every time I had to use modulo for that, but didn't think there was a better way.

Comment: @JonathanDursi: That's a nice solution :) And I agree with the other comment, rounding up to a power of 2 doesn't seem like a good idea in this case... (And I think you can post it as an answer.)

Comment: It seems a bit small to be a whole answer, but I guess it is a bit big for a comment; I'll post it as an answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you've got is fine; if you want to avoid the modulo (since that's very expensive on gpus) you can just do with `j` what you've done with `i`:

```
j = (index - (k*WIDTH*HEIGHT))/WIDTH
```

If you want the logic to be a little clearer, and don't need the original `index`, you can do

```
k = index/(WIDTH*HEIGHT); 
index -= k*WIDTH*HEIGHT; 

j = index/WIDTH; 
index -= j*WIDTH; 

i = index/1;
```

which is then pretty straightforwardly extended to arbitrary dimensions.  You can try tweaking the above by doing things like precomputing `WIDTH*HEIGHT`, say, but I'd just turn up optimization and trust the compiler to do that for you.

The suggestions about rounding up to a power of 2 are correct in the sense that it would speed up the index calculation, but at quite some cost.  In this (not too bad) case, `WIDTH=HEIGHT=100`, it would increase memory requirements of your 3d array by 60% (`WIDTH=HEIGHT=128`) and memory on GPU is generally already tight; and making your arrays powers-of-two size might well introduce problems with bank conflicts, depending on your access patterns.

Answer (score 6):

Try to round your dimensions up to the next power of two. Then you can use bit shifts and masks instead of multiplications, divisions and modulo.

```
index = i | (j | k << HEIGHT_BITS) << WIDTH_BITS;

k = index >> (WIDTH_BITS + HEIGHT_BITS);
j = (index >> WIDTH_BITS) & ((1 << HEIGHT_BITS) - 1);
i = index & ((1 << WIDTH_BITS) - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Only for case when dimensions are power of 2.  Use bitmask. For example if 1st index max value is 4, then it should take 1st 2 bits in index.